# How would people survive anti-gravity curse?

Tags: gravity, survival, modern

Set in the modern day, a meteor lands in the pacific ocean and a green flash of light soon sweep across the globe. All of a sudden every human being alive or dying are experiencing a gravitational acceleration of 10 meters per second squared but away from the Earth instead. It would seem that this curse only targets people and everything else are spared, so those that have survived the purge how do they ensure humanity continue to exist and perhaps even prosper?

Case study 1: People in the airplane must put on a seat belt otherwise they will smash against the ceiling.

Case study 2: People doing dead lift in the gym become doing pull up and their sweat, tears and shit will fall to the floor but their blood splatters on the ceiling.

Case study 3: Divers must adjust their buyoncy otherwise they too will fall into the sky.

Case study 4: Sky diver can only pray.

Case study 5: Wingsuit glider can still fly into enclosed place.

Case study 6: Those inside the submarine simply flip the vessel over... can submarine do that? nevermind.

Case study 7: People who are trapped inside room with a corpse and a saw... (Spoiler: amputated leg is flung against the ceiling and remains there rotting)

Comment: Please let me know if you need more case studies. ;D

Comment: 90% of the world dies within 4-8 days.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: do you mean 4-8 hours ;D

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these case studies? It looks like you are just obfuscating the question

Comment: @L.Dutch: I just want to provide a few scenarios for readers to consider, I hope these examples would help readers to get some senses of what's the curse is about ;D

Comment: No, whoever’s outdoors (40-60%) dies in like 30 minutes.  Takes several days for people in their cars to die from lack of water.  Then about twice that for almost everyone else, after they use up the water in their house, and realize that there’s no more coming because water, power and transportation are all interdependent and they won’t be working soon enough to save most people.

Comment: The person who gets to survive this has 1) a substantial in-house water tank, 2) an enclosed garage and 3) for some reason, the ability to drive upside-down.  That along with a lot of rope, chains and luck might be enough.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: if you played action or simulation game, there is an option to invert the controls ;D

Answer (score 3):

They wouldn't.

Pretty much all of the food we eat comes from the outdoors, and is worked by people who work in the outdoors. With gravity reversed, that food cannot be tended to without some significant modifications in processes. But those modifications can't be made.

I'm going to write off anyone that's outside at the moment of reversal. There might be some instances of people being able to get themselves indoors, but they're going to be few and far between.

I'm similarly going to write off anyone in an aircraft. The problem comes with the fact that aircraft are not designed to go upside down for extended periods - I read a flight manual for a P-51 at one point, and it advised against more than 30 seconds inverted. Even if they could be inverted, the problem comes when it's time to land. At this point, you have people effectively strapped upside down during what is a lengthy landing approach. They would quickly lose consciousness, and the plane would then have nobody controlling it and then crash, incredibly violently. ATC would also be of no use since they would be standing on the ceiling, trying to interact with things that are upside down and mostly out of their reach.

So, who is left? People in buildings. They're now on the ceilings. Let's go through those.

In no particular order: Anyone in a room with a high ceiling, such as a church sanctuary, a fancy office lobby, or whatever, is likely stuck. Some may have catwalks and the like which have doors at higher levels, but most do not. Nor do they offer much in the way of handholds.

Most office buildings have drop ceilings, which will not support the weight of people on them. Numerous, potentially significant, injuries will result from masses of people suddently pressing against them. While there is a structure underneath, it's not going to be the easiest to walk on. I'm going to discount the injuries and say these people will largely be OK. Multi-story buildings would be difficult to navigate but not impossible - Elevators will still work and even many stairways would be functional, although you'd be walking on the bottom and that could get akward.

Most dwellings should be able to support people, so people in their homes should be fine. For now.

You can imagine what's going on with a sports stadium. They're a mixture of open-air and high ceilings.

So we have plenty of people still alive. Now what?

Well. They starve.

In the US, most non-urban areas have parking lots and roads and the like. No indoor car parking. Many people have their cars parked outside, often on paved driveways. There is no good method of securing yourself to the ground - or asphalt, or what have you - to get to that vehicle. Many become completely inaccessible. Train stations often have open and/or high ceilings, and getting people down from there is going to be... difficult. So most people stuck in non-urban buildings cannot get to transportation to leave those buildings.

But what about the people who *can* get to transportation? Well, it turns out, that transportation is useless. It's designed for, well, normal gravity. If a gravity-reversed person managed to get themselves in the car and strap themselves in, they could not go far because their body would be "upside down" as far as it can tell. And then the blood rushes to their head and they pass out and somewhat quickly die.

So, you're stuck in the building you're in, and any way out is a death sentence in some way. Stores are going to be largely inaccessible, and even if you can get into a store, it's going to be extremely difficult to get anything off of the shelves.

While there are solutions to all of these problems, they involve time and effort and figuriong out how to do things, and none of that can really be done without food. Some people might manage it, but they're going to be very, very few in number and largely isolated. And as they adapt things, there's going to be more accidents (Everything falls UP relative to you!), more problems, and things that go wrong. How do you fix a hole in your roof? How do you build a new building? How do you move the heavy machinery that now can't be used out of the way? You pretty much don't.

EDIT: Oh, and submarines? Their ballast tanks and stuff are often open (To one degree or another) on the bottom. Rolling the sub more than a little either way pretty much causes it to sink. They're dead too!

Answer (score 2):

Whoever is not under a roof of some sort and sturdy enough to sustain their weight when this happens is doomed to be dead, because they will fly out to space.

Then those who survived might try to continue their normal life, as long as they have some sort of vehicle under an accessible roof: normally there are no holding points on the ground, so unless a vehicle is reachable under a roof there is no way to venture outside and get food.

Once inside a vehicle it's just a matter of being properly fastened to it to not fly away. This would probably make bicycles obsolete, but will also get rid of all the "fasten your seat belts" campaigns.

Once they can get food they can start adapting the infrastructures to the new situation: remember, to get in and out of a vehicle now every human needs a roof.

Comment: Sales of convertibles would go waaay down